# How can I get vuetify typography classes to work?

Tags: css, vuetify.js, typography

Vuetify supposedly has the following typography classes available:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/

However, they don't work with my vue-cli project. The color ones such as `red--text` work fine, as well others such as `text-lowercase` and `text-uppercase` work fine as well. But things such as `text-h1, text-caption`, etc., no dice.

I'm guessing I have some sort of mis-install, where are these classes supposed to come from?

My project is pretty good sized now (over 30 components) and everything else vue/vuetify is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest 2.3.1 version? All seem to work fine: https://codeply.com/p/6T9lrG8rID

Comment: @zim Ah, that was it. I was using 2.2.22, i upgraded to 2.3.1 and that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typography classes are recent, need to upgrade to latest veutify version (2.3.1). I was using an older version that didn't have them.